# Association property Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I have a newbie question about EF4. 
Let's say I have in my EDMX a class `City` and another one called `State`.

City goes as following:

```
Id
Description
State (obj)
```

And here goes State:

```
Id
Description
Cities (obj collection)
```

My question is very simple. 
When I create a city and set its state `city.State = stateX` does the EF automaticly adds my city to `state.Cities` ? Or do I have to set it manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that depends.

First of all, are you using a model first, a database first or a code first approach?

In model-first you generate your model through EDMX and then let it create the DB for you. As long as there are relationship between the two entities, the foreign key will be generated and you'll have the expected behavior.

In database first is almost the same, but you first create the database (with the foreign keys and all the other stuff) and then derive the EDMX model from it. Again, if the database is structured correctly, no problems.

In Code First, you create your POCO objects like you described (sort of anyway) and then configure the relationships through the fluent interface. If you configure it correctly, the generated database will have the correct foreign keys and again, expected scenario.

Comment: I'm using model first. So since I set all the associations, I only need to set the object at the 1 end, right? In my example, adding state to city would add city to cities in state. Right? Thanks.

Comment: That's correct. Keep in mind to create all correct and required stuff (primary keys, etc) so the generated db will be relationally valid.